# How to interpret term cardinality?

Tags: terminology, requirements, cardinality

An SRS document is provided describing various aspects of the end-product, system maintenance tool. The only paragraph I'm failing to understand is "Component Cardinality". What does this term mean in such context?

The table looks like this:

```
Component Cardinality
=========================
Trigger   | 1..*    | 1..*
Input     | 1..1    | 1..*
Transform | 1..*    | 1..1
```

And the other one:

```
Component | Configuration | Cardinality
=======================================
Trigger   | Schedule      | 1
          | Recurrence    | 1
          | Condition     | 0..*
```

Please help to interpret this properly. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardinality typically refers to relationships and how many of a specific entity relate to another entity. The two tables might refer to input / output.

For example:

```
Component | Inputs | Outputs
----------------------------
Trigger   |  1-1   |  1-*
----------------------------
Input     |  1-1   |  1-*
----------------------------
Transform |  1-*   |  1-1
```

Each of those indicating a 1-1 (One entity to One entity relationship), 1-* (One entity to many entities relationship).

The second chart seems to specific more details regarding a single component and indicating possible "types of Triggers. Perhaps that a single Schedule Trigger will be present (By cardinality 1), as will a single Recurrence Trigger (Also cardinality 1), and that 0-N Condition Triggers may be present in the system (From 0-* cardinality).

This is rather a shot in the dark but I hope it might help some.